# Time dilation effects

Tags: gravity, spacetime, relativity, time-dilation

A random thought just occurred to me
If time dilation due to travelling with speeds closer to 'c' ,can affect the ageing of astronauts , can it affect the decay rate of a plutonium fuel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A similar example is the decay of muons produced by cosmic rays in the upper atmosphere. If not for time dilation (or length contraction, depending on which reference frame you want to use), they would never have time before decaying to reach the surface of the Earth and be detected there!